# Only trigger a azure alert during certain times KQL

Tags: kql

I want a azure alert to "check" and thus alert only between 9am and 10am - this sits wholly within azure monitor and I have just never got along with action group controls

- I have a solution but I wondered if anyone has a better one

  let bd=format_datetime(now(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  let startdate = strcat(bd, ' 09:00 AM');
  let Enddate = strcat(bd, ' 10:00 AM');

Event
where TimeGenerated between (todatetime(startdate) .. todatetime(Enddate))

The alert this actually triggers is a far longer on that runs some very specific code so Ive only included the line which should restrict the code from alerting out of the specified hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution working is always a working solution :)

I would however use [hourofday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hourofdayfunction) in cases like this.

```
| where hourofday(TimeGenerated) == 9 //0900 to 0959
```

Comment: I like that solution